# Is it possible to cut a breadboard?

Tags: arduino, breadboard

I am new to Arduino, so I purchased a starter kit with a 800 pins (or something like that) breadboard.
I would like to know if it is possible to cut it (or saw it) in half on the long side in order to have 2 still working, squared breadboards.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any reason why you couldn't, but as Michael mentioned below, it would not be a good idea to cut it lengthwise as you can no longer use IC's. One issue with cutting it width-wise the way you are describing is that you will most likely lose a row where the cut is made as the contacts will be damaged. The rails at the top and bottom should be fine, as they span the entire length of the breadboard.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend the cutting of the breadboard. To do so you end up losing the ability to plug in IC chips and components that have two rows of pins. Components of this type are typically plugged in across the center gap that I've identified by the yellow line in the picture below.

[image]

There are plenty of sources that sell these breadboards at competitive prices that you would really be better off purchasing an additional board if you need two.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Is it ok to cut it orthogonally to the yellow line in the pic? Will I get 2 working boards? Thank you for the prompt answers guys.

Comment: The prices of these things are so low, why would you? You'll loose mechanical stability and in turn contact falling out. The one on the pic sells for under $3,-